# Regex won't stop matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following set of strings - `"Hello.There"` and `"HelloWorld.There"`

If I do a `'Hello.*'`, RegEx returns both strings. How do I change my expression to return only `"Hello.There"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries in your regex:

```
^Hello\b.*$
```

With word boundaries it won't match `HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

```
\bHello\.There\b
```

the `.` character is a special character in Regex. Escape it.

Comment: Dang it, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be `Hello\.` if you want to return the string when its only contains `Hello.`

In regex a dot(.) means any character. You can escape this by using a escape character like this `\.`

Answer (score -1):

Try this expression
`[Hello.]*`

[gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a simple and good webseite to experiment with Regex